# Apple Mach-O linker warning won't go away

Tags: xcode, warnings, mach-o

I have had this Apple Mach-O linker warning in my project for a few days now.  It is more annoying than anything, but I fear that it may somehow be affecting my app's performance (I have had so many weird issues with Xcode, that I wouldn't doubt anything at this point).  The warning says:

> warning: directory not found for option '-L/Volumes/ZBarSDK/ZBarSDK'

I have no idea what can be causing this or how to fix it.  I have a folder in my app called ZBarSDK, but adding another ZBarSDK does not fix the problem!  I tried searching my computer for a Volumes folder with no luck, either it's not there, or Apple hid it pretty well.  Please let me know what I can do to fix this

Comment: Have u seen this similar thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458739/ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-option ??

Comment: Thanks! worked perfectly for me!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

What I needed to do:

1. Click on your project (targets)
2. Click on Build Settings Under
       Library Search Paths
3. delete the path

Worked wonders!

Answer (score 10):

I found the reference which I had to delete at:

- Target
- Build Settings
- Header Search Paths

Answer (score 6):

Mine was under Framework Search Paths.

The easiest way to find where the bad path is, is to type a part of it in the search box on the top right. That will filter the list to only that one bad path. Deleting it, as the other answers suggest, fixes the problem.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18618187/35690) for more info.