# Apple Mach-O Linker Warning Directory not found

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have spent my last five hours looking for this weird situation a reasonable explanation.

Here is the warning:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/oasis_weng/Desktop/My Life/Life For Myself/Programming/Projects/ChangWeiBo/../xCodeExamples/ShareSDK/ShareSDK_v2.1.0/Extend/SDKExport'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/oasis_weng/Desktop/My Life/Life For Myself/Programming/Projects/ChangWeiBo/../xCodeExamples/ShareSDK/ShareSDK_v2.1.0/Connection'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/oasis_weng/Desktop/My Life/Life For Myself/Programming/Projects/ChangWeiBo/../xCodeExamples/ShareSDK/ShareSDK_v2.1.0/Core'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/oasis_weng/Desktop/My Life/Life For Myself/Programming/Projects/ChangWeiBo/../xCodeExamples/ShareSDK/ShareSDK_v2.1.0/Extend'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/oasis_weng/Desktop/My Life/Life For Myself/Programming/Projects/ChangWeiBo/../xCodeExamples/ShareSDK/ShareSDK_v2.1.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/oasis_weng/Desktop/My Life/Life For Myself/Programming/Projects/ChangWeiBo/../xCodeExamples/ShareSDK/ShareSDK_v2.1.0/UI'
```

However though, I know all those alleged "`missing files`" are truly and actually existed in my application folder and the app runs properly with these files.

The problem of those directories in the warning is the actual path do not include the `../xCodeExamples/ part.`

What should I do to get these warning away?

Comment: Try `Projects(targets)` -> `Build Settings` -> `Library Search Paths` and delete all paths.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You have to follow these step:

- Click on your project (targets)
- Click on Build Settings
- Under "Library Search Paths", delete the paths
- Clean your build and run again.

Good Luck !!

Comment: *Follow-up*: also, if you are borrowing public libraries for your own use, after delete library search paths, you shall remove those APIs and add them back in again. It is very important because the system needs Library Search Paths for those libraries but this entry will only be generated when the libraries are loaded in for the first time.

Comment: I had to delete "${inherited}" only in both debug and release. Not the entire thing. This answer is misleading I think.

Answer (score 43):

For me, the bad path was under Framework Search Paths.

The easiest way to find where the bad path is, is to type a part of it in the search box on the top right. That will filter the list to only that one bad path. Deleting it, as the other answer suggests, fixes the problem.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18618187/35690) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. This solved the problem for me too specifically clearing the Framework Search Paths. +1

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since the question has `-F` in the path, which stands for framework, libraries use `-L`.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem today with different solution (might help someone).

If your source directory name `$(SRCROOT)` include spaces, use
`"$(SRCROOT)"` instead of `$(SRCROOT)` in Library Search Paths.

Let's say your directory name is "A B C". If you use `$(SRCROOT)`
you might get something like:

```
directory not found for option '-LA'
directory not found for option '-LB'
directory not found for option '-LC'
```

Comment: My warning was related to the `$(SRCROOT)` listing as well. For some reason mine had gotten set to `\"$(SRCROOT)/a_project_subfolder\"`... Not sure why the escape chars were added as they seemed to be the problem (plus I removed the subfolder). So yes, `"$(SRCROOT)"` was what I ended up using. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Also check Build Settings->Framework Search Path for unused folders (this kind of warning happened to me when I deleted Carthage from the project today)