# How to fix this Mach-O Linker issue?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, compiler-errors

I keep getting this linker warning, and inconsistently, every few builds an error?

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/PROJECT2/Desktop/Ping Pong - Ultimate/Tap'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LPing’
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L-'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LPong’
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LUltimate’
```

It keeps saying this but I have no L's anywhere in my project?

I would put more to this question but I literally have no idea as to what's going on? Where can I even begin to search for where these "L's" are hidden?

If more info is needed, please tell me and I'll try to find!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have looked harder. The exact answer, in detail, is right here: [Apple Mach-O Linker Warning Directory not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644982/apple-mach-o-linker-warning-directory-not-found)