# How to fix linker command failed with exit code 1(use - v to see invocation) error?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios7, ios5

i am getting the following error how to fix it.

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-FFRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F='

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

i have tried the following way but still getting the same problem.

i have refered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458739/ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-option) and also i removed all the frameworks and added once again still same problem occurs. can any once help.

Comment: See if this can help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061772/directory-not-found-apple-mach-o-linker-warning-but-library-search-path-and-fram

Comment: @ujjwal i will try