# Xcode linker issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, testflight

Everything was fine. I just deleted the old TestFlight folder from my Xcode project, and then dragged the new TestFlight SDK 3.0 into my project, and tried to build and got these errors.

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-L"/Desktop/Work/Games/ClanKingdom/Game/src/Classes/TestFlightSDK1.2.4"'
>   ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-L"/Desktop/Work/Games/ClanKingdom/Game/src/Classes/Flurry"' ld:
>   warning: directory not found for option
>   '-L"/Desktop/Work/Games/ClanKingdom/Game/src/TestFlightSDK2.0.0"' ld:
>   warning: directory not found for option
>   '-L"/Desktop/Work/Games/ClanKingdom/Game/src/Flurry"' ld: warning:
>   directory not found for option
>   '-F"/Desktop/Work/Games/ClanKingdom/Game/src/FacebookSDK"' ld: library
>   not found for -lFlurry_4.2.3 clang: error: linker command failed with
>   exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Why would it be giving me some issue for Flurry? I've not changed anything for Flurry, also I'm not sure why it's trying to link those older versions of TestFlight as I've deleted them.

Any ideas?

Comment: _I'm not sure why it's trying to link those older versions of TestFlight as I've deleted them_ -- apparently you haven't deleted them enough.

Comment: Ha, I have they don't exist in those directories anymore!

Comment: It's not enough to delete the library files, you need to modify your Xcode project configuration to remove reference to them as well. Fortunately Xcode makes this somewhat easy, in that you can search for, for example, TestFlight within your project's configuration to find the references.

Comment: Thanks I resolved the issue with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458739/ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you've resolved this issue already, but for completeness you were linking your libraries using absolute file paths to a location where they no longer existed.

It looks like you were linking to the TestFlight library on your desktop. This is a really bad idea, you should either keep all your libraries in one sensible location, or keep copies of them locally in the source code of your project. That way you can modify your 'Library Search Paths' to a relative link, e.g.

```
$(SRCROOT)/Code\ Folder/Third\ Party\ Classes/Google\ Analytics
```

So `$(SRCROOT)` will point to the directory in which your xcode project lives, and you can manually enter the path to your library from there. The advantage being you will be able to move your libraries around with your codebase, but also in this instance simply replace the files within the folder at the path you've chosen, and everything should magically work!