# Using rbenv install throws an error

Tags: ruby, homebrew, rbenv

I'm using Homebrew rbenv. `brew doctor` comes out fine. `rbenv install 2.0.0-p451` gives the following error message:

```
user$ rbenv install 2.0.0-p451 
Downloading ruby-2.0.0-p451.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/9227787a9636551f1749ee8394b5ffe5
Installing ruby-2.0.0-p451...

BUILD FAILED

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/4h/ty8nj6c144b5cmhcrt0hd3cw0000gn/T/ruby-build.20140501101240.6245
Results logged to /var/folders/4h/ty8nj6c144b5cmhcrt0hd3cw0000gn/T/ruby-build.20140501101240.6245.log

Last 10 log lines:
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451/lib'
installing default openssl libraries
1 warning generated.
linking shared-object date_core.bundle
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451/lib'
linking shared-object openssl.bundle
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451/lib'
linking shared-object ripper.bundle
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451/lib'
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

I tried googling it but not luck. Any tips?

p.s. I tried other ruby versions but same issue (although the last 10 lines of the log are slightly different).

Edit: installing version 1.9.3-p545 works fine.

Comment: provide `/var/folders/4h/ty8nj6c144b5cmhcrt0hd3cw0000gn/T/ruby-build.20140501101240.6245.log` the log

Comment: also provide output for `ls /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451/lib`

Comment: Here goes! http://paste2.org/4JaLvXF1

Comment: where is output of ls?

Comment: I don't understand how or why, but pastebin truncates the log file. I tried to paste the last part of the log file and this is the result: http://pastebin.com/XgQk0vxr

Comment: I am trying to upload the last part of the log file but I cannot.

Comment: Here it goes: http://pastebin.com/7juPGLyv (I had to remove some lines to stop pastebin from truncating the file).

Comment: possible duplicate of [‘ld: warning: directory not found for option’](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458739/ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-option)

Comment: @gdiazc I meant output for command `ls /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451/lib` not a log

Comment: @gdiazc have you linux, or osx?

Comment: OS X. The output requested: ``ls: /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451/lib: No such file or directory``

Answer (score 1):

`brew cleanup` and remove this `/var/folders/4h/ty8nj6c144b5cmhcrt0hd3cw0000gn/T/ruby-build.20140501101240.6245` file.

I remember i removed all `/var/folders/4h` folder (wasn't exactly such name, but then i removed all folders in `/var/folders/` and there wasn't no problem).

Comment: Is it safe to empty ``/var/folders/``?

Comment: I dont know, but remove that file and it should be enough.