# installing ruby with rbenv error: ld: warning: directory not found for option

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I'm trying to install ruby 2.0.0-p247 with rbenv but the build keeps failing. It did work before:

```
$ rbenv versions
  system
  2.0.0-p195
  2.0.0-p353
* 2.1.0 (set by /Users/nemo/.ruby-version)
```

I looked at [Using rbenv install throws an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23405264/using-rbenv-install-throws-an-error) and tried the suggestion but it didn't help

I tried the following before trying to install

```
sudo rm -rf /var/folders/yt/5nww85g11gdgqcz4tcl1dndc0000gn/T/*
sudo rm -rf /tmp/ruby*

$ brew update
Already up-to-date.
$ brew doctor
Your system is ready to brew.

$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix

$ sudo rbenv install 2.0.0-p451
 Last 10 log lines:
 installing default openssl libraries
 linking shared-object dl/callback.bundle
 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nemo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451/lib'
 linking shared-object openssl.bundle
 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nemo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451/lib'
 linking shared-object nkf.bundle
 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nemo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451/lib'
 linking shared-object ripper.bundle
 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/nemo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451/lib'
```

What else I could try?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/28651

basically:

```
brew uninstall readline
brew install readline
```

solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the appropriate (i.e., writable) directory permission of `~/.rbenv/versions/YOUR_VERSION/` is not given for the user who runs `rbenv install`.

Obviously it is very unlikely to be the case in the op's situation where `sudo` is used. However, if the rbenv environment has been set up by the superuser and if you nevertheless run `rbenv install` as a non-privileged user (without `sudo`), the process fails to create the directory like `lib/` under the said directory and so fails fatally. The event of the failure (in creating the directory) is not explicitly reported in the error message as of `rbenv` 1.1.2 and so may be slightly perplexing.