# Use pod install MWPhotoBrowser error

Tags: ios, objective-c

when i run my project, Then it will be error like this:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/Andou/Desktop/JobProject/yundoumiao/yundoumiaoRV2/yundoumiaoRV2/Pods/build/Debug-iphoneos'
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MWPhoto", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in YDMediaManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MWPhotoBrowser", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DetailViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in PhotoViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

how can i solve this problem.please tell me. Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you run pod install?

Comment: This post has Possible duplicate, for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458739/ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-option