# Xcode error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode

I wanted to build a project and i found this problem,

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/igorkhomenko/workspace/quickblox-ios-sdk/Framework'

ld: library not found for -lPods

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can I get your help please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458739/ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-option

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like the class Algebra5FirstViewController is compile multiple time.

Can you make sure that the .m and .mm is only included once in your project sources in Xcode? You can also confirm this by checking in the compile log (last icon at the right, next to the breakpoints icon) and see that confirm that it is only compiled once.

Also, if this class is part of a library that you link against and you have a class with the same name, you could have the same error.

Finally, you can try a clean and rebuild, just in case the old object files are still present and there is some junk in the compiled files. Just in case...

Answer (score 0):

You're using cocoapods. Try to open the workspace and not the project file. If there's no workspace, maybe you need to run `pod install` that will add all the dependency and create the workspace.