# Linking error when building TutorialHelloWorld in UnityPro4.6.0f3, Xcode5.0.2 (5A3005) and IOS 8.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, metaio

I did my best to follow the tutorial "Webinar 10:Fundamentals of the Metaio SDK Unity"  (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AW47EKRKEdw) but they use a different version of Metaio than me(I'm using metaio SDK (Version 22/05/2014)).

I manage to produce a project in Xcode imported form UnityPro.
After I add: "libxml2.dylib" and "metaiosdk" to the Xcode project;  and build the project, I get 130 errors and 7 warnings.

The warning just before the error list says:
  "ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/900lbs-intern02/Desktop/metaio-test/Libraries"'

And the top error says:
  "std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >::insert(unsigned long, unsigned long, char)", referenced from:"

I tried to solve the warning by doing what is suggested in([‘ld: warning: directory not found for option’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458739/ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-option)). Before building again, I cleaned the project(command+shift+option + k) and now I get the following 7 warnigs and 1 error(I will show the last warning and the error):

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/900lbs-intern02/Desktop/metaio-test/Libraries"'
ld: library not found for -liPhone-lib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Can someone tell me what is going on? 
Specially, how to solve the ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/900lbs-intern02/Desktop/metaio-test/Libraries"'   Warning?

I will appreciate anyone's help.

Comment: Check the library (and header) search paths, the message indicates that the linked libraries are not found at the given location. Though one reason for that could simply be that they haven't been built due to a different, preceding error. Check the build log for the very first error that appears.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem:

+First I upgraded to  Xcode 6.1.1

+Then I added a couple of libraries/frameworks that where missing:

```
    -libc++.dylib

    -Security.framework

    -CoreImage.framework
```