# linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, objective-c, clang

I am getting some errors and warnings when I build my IOS project

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/parikshitpatel/Documents/IphoneDevelopment/FH/funkiorangemobile_iphonehealthadviceapp/Social'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LMedia/Twitter/Twitter'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LLibrary/Libraries'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/parikshitpatel/Documents/IphoneDevelopment/FH/funkiorangemobile_iphonehealthadviceapp0/Social'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L&'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LHeaders'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LMedia/Twitter'
ld: library not found for -lOAuth
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am not getting how to fix this error can some one help?

Comment: no i m not using pods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your Library path is incorrect.
Try to go to:   **Targets - Build Phases - Link Binary with Libraries**
 and add your **Twitter Library/Framework**

Comment: Have a look on this post: [SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458739/ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-option)

Answer (score 1):

In your Folder path there are blank spaces between them. for example:

```
/Users/parikshitpatel/Documents/IphoneDevelopment/FH/funkiorangemobile_iphonehealthadviceapp/Social Media
```

In your Library dependencies write `Social\ Media` instead.

Do the same for other library.

Comment: No there are no spaces between name

Answer (score 1):

For me I was opening the .xcodeproj Xcode project instead of the .xcworkspace workspace.  I'm pretty new to iOS development, but this feels similar to opening the wrong gradle file in Android Studio

Comment: What the hell, It was just that for me... Why? what's the difference between both?