# "linker command failed with exit code 1" when i add new TwitterKit by pods?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, cocoapods, linker-errors

Yesterday after update pods, a have this 74 errors.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TWTRDateUtil", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TwitterKit(TWTRTweetView.o)
      objc-class-ref in TwitterKit(TWTRDateFormatter.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TWTRScribeService", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TwitterKit(Twitter.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TWTRGuestSessionManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TwitterKit(Twitter.o)   "_TWTRCoreVersion", referenced from:
      +[Twitter assertValidTwitterCoreVersion] in TwitterKit(Twitter.o)   "_TWTRUserSessionVerifierIntervalDaily", referenced from:
      -[Twitter kitDidFinishStarting] in TwitterKit(Twitter.o)   "_TWTRNetworkingUserAgentHeaderKey", referenced from:
      -[Twitter startWithConsumerKey:consumerSecret:] in TwitterKit(Twitter.o)   "_TWTRAuthAppOAuthDeniedKey", referenced from:
      -[TWTRWebAuthenticationProvider requestAccessTokenWithAuthResponse:completion:] in TwitterKit(TWTRWebAuthenticationProvider.o)
```

linker command failed with exit code 1.

My new pods:

```
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'TwitterKit'
pod 'Crashlytics'
```

Before:

```
pod 'Fabric/Core', '~> 1.2.3'
pod 'Fabric/Crashlytics', '~> 1.2.3'
pod 'Fabric/Twitter', '~> 1.2.3'
```

This answers don't help me: [add your Twitter Library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27818016/1362393), [add libstdc++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31465353/1362393)

Also I try add  Twitter.Framework, Social.framework, Accounts.framework.

I use two big libs with Linker Flags -ObjC

Comment: Have you tried to clean the Pods? `rm -rf Pods/ Podfile.lock ; pod install` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just went through this today. I had to also install the pod for `TwitterCore`. Add the following line to your `Podfile` and run `pod install` again:

```
pod 'TwitterCore'
```

If that doesn't work then also try going to `Build Settings` and search in the search bar for "`other linker flags`". Once it finds it just double click in the area to the right where it lists the actual flags.

Remove all the flags by using the `-` icon and then add the following flag using the `+` icon: `$(inherited)`