# R can not find gfortran

Tags: c++, r, gfortran

I have been trying to tackle this problem for quite some time now, and it seems like I just can't. After loading some packages I try to source a C++ file, and this is what happens:

```
sourceCpp("Desktop/studie/master/Scriptie/R files/simulExpRcpp.cpp");  

Error in sourceCpp("Desktop/studie/master/Scriptie/R files/simulExpRcpp.cpp") : 
Error 1 occurred building shared library.
WARNING: The tools required to build C++ code for R were not found.
Please install Command Line Tools for XCode (or equivalent).

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2'
```

I have installed gfortran as indicated [here](http://www.thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/rcpp-rcpparmadillo-and-os-x-mavericks-lgfortran-and-lquadmath-error), and double checked whether I correctly installed CommandLineTools. Also, my system runs on OS X Mavericks 10.9.5.

I assume the problem has something to do with the library, for which some possible solutions are given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458739/ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-option). However, as I am quite new to R, I do not really get all the subtleties yet and the solutions are somewhat abracadabra to me.

Is there someone who can explain to me very carefully what I can do to resolve the problem? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: The error message tells you what to do. "Please install Command Line Tools for XCode (or equivalent)"

Comment: You haven't told us how you have your system set up. My guess is that you used homebrew to install part of it, and aren't telling us.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Like I said, I have installed Command Line Tools, which I checked with terminal.

Comment: @BondedDust: I installed gfortran using this command in terminal: 
    curl -O http://r.research.att.com/libs/gfortran-4.8.2-darwin13.tar.bz2 -C /

I now see that this might have something to do with homebrew, will dive into that

Comment: Update: R looks for the file in "-L/usr/local/lib/gcc" while it appears to be in "-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc". Is there a way to change this?

Comment: I can think of  some possibilities and I not sure which one to recommend. You might try posting that particular question on SuperUser.com. You may need to change:  the $PATH variable so that location is searched or put in the proper environment variable or put a dylib in the expected directory pointing to the actual location. And I'm still worried about the message saying no command line tools were found. Fortran is not a command line tool.

Comment: I had a simliar problem and I can recommend the installers found at https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases