# finding directory in Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, directory

I've been getting this following warning everytime I build my project:

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>    '-F/Users/macbookair1/Documents/programming/My App/build/Debug-iphoneos'

How do i resolve this issue?

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458739/ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-option

Comment: that was it, thanks @Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 1):

What you have done before.

1. remove Debug-iphoneos
2. you can check "search paths"
3. search the name of **My App**,and rename
4. delete tests

Comment: can you be more descriptive.. delete Debug-iphoneos from where? and rename my app where? delete what test