# directory not found for option FacebookSDK

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I am getting the following error when I run my app:

**ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/qlxmac01/Desktop/iPhone Apps from Google Docs/NinjaBites/../../Documents/FacebookSDK'**

It uses an older version of the FacebookSDK from around 2012-2013 but I am not sure why the app will not compile.  I'm assuming that the problem has to do with the FacebookSDK.framework

Could someone please point me in the right direction of how to fix this error or what I should even be looking for to fix this problem?

Here is a snapshot of what I am getting:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happen when your project  not able to find the your facebookSDK framework because of shifting the project from one directory to other try to delete facebook sdk from project file and add the facebook sdk again.

Comment: can you post snap shot of that to get the clear picture of that error

Comment: you can check  this link- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458739/ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-option

Comment: I deleted the search paths, deleted FacebookSDK again then re-added... still same error, so you know of anything else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook usually recommends putting their facebookSDK into the `~/Documents` folder, check to see if this or anything involved with facebookSDK is on your iCloud only. This was the issue for me when I ran into this.