# updated core plot library in old project

Tags: ios, ios9, core-plot, xcode7

Hi I have updated core plot library for graphs in my project(updated header files and make pod file for `libcoreplot-cocoatouch.a` library)but it continuously giving me error like "directory not found for option '-FFramework'" as below and I am using xcode 7 - ios 9 and I have tried almost all the solution found on stackoverflow and other sites  but nothing is working can anyone help me out with this please.

> error : ld: warning: directory not found for option '-FFramework'
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386   clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: I have improved formatting of your question which will improve readability. Please add more details with the sites and example you have tried

Comment: i have tried  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458739/ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-option) and others too in which solution like changes in library search path,header search path,edit framework search path  and remove library and add it again etc etc .

Comment: Can you post the contents of your pod file?