# XCode giving me following "Apple Mach-O Linker" Warnings

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, warnings, mach-o

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Hagile /Workspace/Github/MyApp/Code/Libraries/FacebookSDK/build/facebook-ios-sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/facebook-ios-sdk.build/Objects-normal/armv7'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Hagile /Workspace/Github/MyApp/Code/Libraries/FacebookSDK/build/facebook-ios-sdk.build/Release-iphoneos/facebook-ios-sdk.build/Objects-normal/armv7s'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Hagile /Workspace/Github/MyApp/Code/Libraries/FacebookSDK/build/Release-iphoneos'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Hagile /Workspace/Github/MyApp/Code/Libraries/FacebookSDK/build/Release-iphonesimulator'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Hagile /Workspace/Github/MyApp/Code/Libraries/FacebookSDK/build/Release-universal'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Hagile /Workspace/Github/MyApp/Code/build/Debug-iphoneos'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Hagile /Workspace/Github/MyApp/Code/build/Release-iphoneos'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Hagile /Workspace/Github/MyApp/Code/Libraries/FacebookSDK/build'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Hagile /Workspace/Github/MyApp/Code/Pods/NewRelicAgent/NewRelic_iOS_Agent_5.2.1'
```

I am getting above warnings in these specifications:

- XCode v.6.3.
- iOS Simulator v.8.3.0.
- OSX v.10.10.3.
- Using CocoaPods too.

How to prevent XCode from generating this warnings?

Comment: are you using coco pods?

Comment: @Mr.T, Yes – I'm using CocoaPods.

Comment: are u using workspace file or xcode file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do like

targets -> build settings -->'**Framework search Paths**' and '**Library Search Paths**' delete the particular path which one you want/which one not available and add again.

for more [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458739/ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-option)

Comment: @hagile --then you need to Open workspace file, not project file. Cocoapods automatically creates a xcworkspace file on the same directory as xcproject file

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, you were right, your answer help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @tanx buddy , tanx a lot