# iTunes Store operation succeeded with a warning

Tags: ios, xcode7

[image]Getting major error when I try to upload app to iTunes.  From Xcode, select Product, archive, then I say "Upload" get this message:

Error ITMS-90032 Invalid image path - no image found at the path referenced under key CFBundleIconFiles: ""

if I say "validate" I get:

iTunes Store operation succeeded with a warning. The resulting API analysis file is too large[image]

If i just say "export" I get a folder on the desktop which I don't know what its for?

Any pointers? This is a nightmare maze of complication after complication.
on Android... its a 5 min job to publish an app

using Xcode 7.1

Comment: The proper order of steps are:

Comment: Try this again: The proper order of steps are: Product...Archive, Validate, resolve issues raised by Validate. Repeat as often as necessary.  Once your app successfully validates, then Upload.  As for API Analysis, that's just a preliminary check that, in this case, results in a warning that the resulting analysis file is larger than normal.  If you proceed with the Upload, within a few minutes (or hours) you might get an email detailing any API problems, if there really are any.

Comment: what are the issues you are referring to ?  The "normal" ones that come up when you compile and test the app ?

Comment: By issues, I meant anything that is more than a warning -- it's not the same type of stuff you get compiling and testing.  Sometimes, though, it is something you wonder why it wasn't caught in the compiling phase!   Usually, an issue is specific enough (such as a missing file or framework) that it's easy to fix.  For the more esoteric issues, that's what Stack Overflow is for.  If you get the green checkmark that Validation succeeded, then you can proceed with the Upload.

Comment: added some pictures. Don't know what the "green checkmark" is: This is my first experience with IOS.  Also getting an annoying warn message which I can't get rid of. It is a warning, so I have ignored it so far.  What is the function os the "Tests" folder for the app ? could I not delete it and maybe this message will go ?

Comment: Directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.1.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'

Comment: For that last comment, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458739/ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-option    The part about the F option is about halfway down.

Comment: I have removed the issue described above plus any other warning (yellow) message.  My app now has zero issues at testing time.  Yet the same is still happening. no change. Any clues? I have, in desperation,  contacted Apple support ???