# "directory not found for option '-L/..' " Cocoapods issue

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, armv7

I'm using the [CocoaLumberjack library](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack) in my Xcode project. I'm running into an issue when updating to the latest (2.2.0) version via `pod install`. Attaching screen of the error I'm seeing. Error description reads:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/$(PROJECT_DIR)/build/Debug-iphoneos'
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_ddLogLevel", referenced from:
(Various project files referencing 'ddLogLevel')
```

[image: Xcode error screenshot]

armv7 is supported as a valid architecture by my CocoaLumberjack target settings.

Tried the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18618187/3347084 but after doing so I received a different compiler error `ld: library not found for -lGoogleAnalyticsServices`. Could not fix and decided not to go too far down that rabbit hole unless I'm sure it's necessary to fix my original issue.