# id warning: directory not found for option

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, frameworks

I have been using Xcode 6 and I am using Xcode 7.3 beta 3 now and I got this warning

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-F/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.3.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'

I've read something to go to "Project > Build Sittings > Search Path > Framework Search Paths" and I found it empty as you can see in the picture below.

Does anybody know how or what should I do?

[image: Picture]

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458739/ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-option

Comment: Library Search Paths is the same :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**: Creating a new scheme should do the trick: `Products > Scheme > New Scheme` select the correct target and give it a name. Also clean and rebuild your project (`Product > Clean` and `Product > Build`)

---

Do you have the 9.3 simulator dowloaded on your system? You can check by going to `Xcode > Preferences > Downloads`. If not download the version(s) you need from the list.

[image: Screenshot of Xcode Downloads view]

Comment: I got http://oi66.tinypic.com/biszs0.jpg .. what should I add? "iPhoneOS9.3" is written but it's better that you tell me :)

Comment: Could you try creating a new scheme? `Products > Scheme > New Scheme` select the correct target and give it a name. Do you still get the warning? Also clean and rebuild your project (`Product > Clean` and `Product > Build`)

Comment: Same thing when I used Xcode 6 and updated to Xcode 7.3 beta , can I tell you what it is?

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: I got 3 warnings http://oi63.tinypic.com/kstci.jpg .. I filled the AppIcon But the Brand assets I got these

Comment: Regarding the assets catalog, have look at [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/AddingLaunchImagestoanAssetCatalog.html). If your problem persists consider creating a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the "framework search paths" to the directory of your iOS project e.g. `/Users/...`

Comment: Can you explain more please?

Comment: So say your iOS project is on your computer at the path `/Users/Sameeha/Documents/MyProject`, you'd put that line into both the release and debug Framework Search Paths setting under Build Settings

Comment: Did it work? :D If it did, could you mark my answer as correct please.

Comment: @Sameeha if this answer worked for you please mark the answer as the best answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

it is because xcode doesn't find path to look for framework.

Go to "Project > Build Sittings > Search Path > Framework Search Paths" and add Below value in it may it will solve your problem.

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)
```

Comment: I added it to the "Release" and "Debug" nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar warning with the -L option, for library search paths. I removed what it had and only kept $(inherited). That removed the warning.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: Can you clarify how this is not an answer? The question asked what should be done to get rid of the warning. My answer shows one approach that got rid of the warning. What further clarification is needed?

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering) to get an idea about what answers should be like in SO. About your answer it belongs in the comment section under the question. Sometimes questions doesn't need a full blown answer a comment also can help. But in your case you're still to get commenting privilege until you get it stick to the guidelines of answering. If you post a low quality answer and the community start to down vote SO policies will render you unable to ask question and eventually make your account at risk. Just a heads up.

Comment: Thanks for your input but I respectfully disagree with your assessment. I read the link you provided and I think I did exactly what it says under “Answer the question”. I have a more specific approach (use $(inherited) in the field) than other answers and it works. And it actually answers his question, which is simply and literally “what can I do?”. I think that goes beyond a comment.  Not trying to argue here or cause trouble but I suggest you rethink your assessment. Thanks for the heads up about downvotes. Have a good day.