# ld: framework not found AdSupport for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/extentia/Desktop/Flurry-iOS-6.4.0/Flurry'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/extentia/Desktop/Flurry-iOS-6.4.0/FlurryAds'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LiPhone'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LSDK'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LviPhone'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L6.4.0/Flurry-iOS-6.4.0/Flurry'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L6.4.0/Flurry-iOS-6.4.0/FlurryAds'
ld: framework not found AdSupport for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I deleted iAd.framework and adsupport.framework but still it gives an error

Comment: see this once it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458739/ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-option

Comment: Not working this. Still it shows this linker error.  ld: framework not found AdSupport for architecture armv7 .

Answer (score 1):

For me cleaning a project and its derived data did the trick.