# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) - Xcode - 9.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Don't close this because some one has already asked this question. I have tried all the way to get this fixed. It is totally different issue.

I am trying to get FCM working on my iOS App. I have Xcode 9.2 running. When I run the App from Xcode I get the following error:

```
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/Xps/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PushNotification-aszvabepdrbugidxvmpotzzhsfow/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleToolboxForMac'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/Xps/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PushNotification-aszvabepdrbugidxvmpotzzhsfow/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Protobuf'
ld: library not found for -lGoogleToolboxForMac
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried all the ways given in SO or every where.. Like loading xcworkspace and not xcodeproject, few other troubleshooting. Still the same.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [‘ld: warning: directory not found for option’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458739/ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-option)

Comment: search for `lGoogleToolboxForMac` in your project. Looks like its missing.

Comment: Try building the two frameworks referenced first (set the scheme to the one for the framework and build it and then set the scheme back to your main roject).

Comment: @JeremyP: I am not sure how to do it? I am totally new to swift and xCode.