# Framework Linking

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift4

I have created a simple framework for the arithmetic operations and another project for using that framework, even after adding the framework, It is giving framework not found or framework not found MathFunctionFramework (where MathFunctionFramework is the name of my framework)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your framework is added to the `Embedded Binaries` section on the General pane. Also check that your framework appears in the `Link Binary With Libraries` & `Embed Frameworks` sections in the Build Phases pane.

If the framework is being dynamically linked, please check that the correct path value is present in the `Framework Search Paths` setting in Build Settings.

Comment: Rhuari Glen, Even after adding that also, It is showing the same error

Comment: @Sudhir have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the project? Use cmd + alt + shift + k as well as cmd + shift + k

Comment: Another couple of things to check would be:
1. Check classes, structs, functions etc have `public` before them if you wish to use them outside the framework.
2. Check that your framework contains a `modules` folder with a `modulemap` file within it, this can be done by expanding the framework in Finder

Comment: @Sudhir please see my above comment

Comment: I have checked the first option and the second option there is no such issue related to it

Comment: @Sudhir are you dynamically linking this framework? Please check you have included the path of your framework in the *Framework Search Paths* in your Build Settings

Comment: Yes I am dynamically linking my framework and  I have added that also in Framework Search Paths

Comment: @Sudhir Check this answer. May be what you're after. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18618187/6351482