# Flutter iOS emulator not reading packages / cocoa pods

Tags: package, cocoapods, flutter, emulation

I just updated my flutter version and all my packages and now my iOS emulator isn't working.  I can successfully launch my app in Android but not iOS or physical apple device.  I'm receiving the following errors...

> Failed to build iOS app Error output from Xcode build: ↳
>       ** BUILD FAILED **
>        Xcode's output: ↳
>       === BUILD TARGET FirebaseCore OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
>       ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/charlesclevelandjr/Desktop/myfavkpop/example/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseAuth'
>       ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/charlesclevelandjr/Desktop/myfavkpop/example/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseDatabase'
>       ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/charlesclevelandjr/Desktop/myfavkpop/example/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/firebase_admob'
>       ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/charlesclevelandjr/Desktop/myfavkpop/example/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/firebase_auth'
>       ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/charlesclevelandjr/Desktop/myfavkpop/example/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/firebase_core'
>       ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/charlesclevelandjr/Desktop/myfavkpop/example/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/firebase_database'
>       ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/charlesclevelandjr/Desktop/myfavkpop/example/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/firebase_storage'
>       ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/charlesclevelandjr/Desktop/myfavkpop/example/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/flutter_webview_plugin'
>       ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/charlesclevelandjr/Desktop/myfavkpop/example/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/google_sign_in'
>       ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/charlesclevelandjr/Desktop/myfavkpop/example/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/image_picker'
>       ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/charlesclevelandjr/Desktop/myfavkpop/example/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/myfavkpop'
>       ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/charlesclevelandjr/Desktop/myfavkpop/example/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb'
>       ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/charlesclevelandjr/Desktop/myfavkpop/example/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/onesignal'
>       ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/charlesclevelandjr/Desktop/myfavkpop/example/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/path_provider'
>       ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/charlesclevelandjr/Desktop/myfavkpop/example/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared_preferences'
>       ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/charlesclevelandjr/Desktop/myfavkpop/example/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/url_launcher'
>       ld: library not found for -lFirebaseAuth
>       clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) Could not build the application for the simulator.
>   Error launching application on iPhone X.

Any ideas on where the problem may be or how to reset the emulator completely?

Comment: have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458739/ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-option

Answer (score 1):

Open Runner file with Xcode and File > WorkspaceSetting and set as attached image .

[image: Try to run by using Xcode File>WorkspaceSetting>and Select Lagacy Build System]

And then Run from your Xcode run button .