# Flutter - Getting an error archiving with Xcode

Tags: xcode, flutter

I finished up my small flutter app, where I am using a webview (webview_flutter: ^0.3.5+3). All works great on simulator.

I have run flutter build iOS --release, selected runner from targets and set it to generic iOS device.

Now I want to archive it in Xcode but I keep getting this error about "Library not found for -lwebview_flutter"

I can't seem to find a solution and would really appreciate some help

[image]

Comment: Sometimes I've seen it where things go wrong with the pod install. Try cleaning the build directory first (`flutter clean`),  then `flutter build ios` (ignore a failure here), then cd ios/ and `pod install`, then open xcode and try archive. Hopefully that works for you! And an fyi - I recently removed it, but I have been able to archive the webview flutter library in the past...

Comment: @rmtmckenzie I did as you suggested but still getting the error... its driving me mad

Comment: oh when you opened the xcode project did you open the .xcproject or the .xcworkspace? You have to open the .xcworkspace.

Comment: @GY22 Any resolution on this? I am getting a very similar error

Comment: Posting in case anyone comes across this. What worked for me was opening the .xcworkspace ***instead*** of the .xcproject file. From here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40530866/1183321

Comment: @Jordan I'm doing that now, but `archive` is disabled and I want that. How did you fix that?

Comment: @Jordan never mind, I had to choose `Generic iOS Device`. Thanks for this

Comment: @GY22 I think you can update your library on folder `your_project/ios>` `pod install` or `pod install --repo-update`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Flutter plugins that installed Pods in the iOS build, make sure that you've opened the Xcode project with `.xcworkspace`

If that still didn't work, you can try regenerating the iOS build folder by deleting the `/ios` folder and run `flutter create --platforms=ios` to generate project files for the iOS build.