# ** BUILD FAILED ** on migrate android to iOS

Tags: ios, macos, flutter, dart

I started a project on android, when i finished on android version, i started developing for ios on Flutter. But I found some errors that I can not solve in any way, here are the errors:

I tried flutter clean, pod update, pod install, but not this work for me

And now error on debug:

Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:

```
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/every/AndroidStudioProjects/clinica_sorriso/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKCoreKit'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/every/AndroidStudioProjects/clinica_sorriso/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKLoginKit'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/every/AndroidStudioProjects/clinica_sorriso/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseAuth'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/every/AndroidStudioProjects/clinica_sorriso/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCore'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/every/AndroidStudioProjects/clinica_sorriso/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseDatabase'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/every/AndroidStudioProjects/clinica_sorriso/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseFirestore'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/every/AndroidStudioProjects/clinica_sorriso/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseInstanceID'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/every/AndroidStudioProjects/clinica_sorriso/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseStorage'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/every/AndroidStudioProjects/clinica_sorriso/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTMSessionFetcher'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/every/AndroidStudioProjects/clinica_sorriso/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/every/AndroidStudioProjects/clinica_sorriso/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Protobuf'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/every/AndroidStudioProjects/clinica_sorriso/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/cloud_firestore'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/every/AndroidStudioProjects/clinica_sorriso/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/firebase_auth'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/every/AndroidStudioProjects/clinica_sorriso/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/firebase_core'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/every/AndroidStudioProjects/clinica_sorriso/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/firebase_database'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/every/AndroidStudioProjects/clinica_sorriso/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/firebase_storage'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/every/AndroidStudioProjects/clinica_sorriso/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/flutter_facebook_login'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/every/AndroidStudioProjects/clinica_sorriso/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/gRPC-C++'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/every/AndroidStudioProjects/clinica_sorriso/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/gRPC-Core'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/every/AndroidStudioProjects/clinica_sorriso/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/geolocator'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/every/AndroidStudioProjects/clinica_sorriso/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/google_api_availability'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/every/AndroidStudioProjects/clinica_sorriso/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/google_maps_flutter'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/every/AndroidStudioProjects/clinica_sorriso/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/google_sign_in'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/every/AndroidStudioProjects/clinica_sorriso/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/image_picker'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/every/AndroidStudioProjects/clinica_sorriso/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/every/AndroidStudioProjects/clinica_sorriso/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/location_permissions'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/every/AndroidStudioProjects/clinica_sorriso/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/every/AndroidStudioProjects/clinica_sorriso/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/onesignal_flutter'
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/every/AndroidStudioProjects/clinica_sorriso/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/url_launcher'
    ld: framework not found Bolts
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone Xʀ.
```

Comment: maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/9458789/5464805

Comment: I found solution, i create new project and pull my files, just this