# Error - linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoapods

I'm new to XCode Mac and IPhone development. So probably I'm missing something obvious here.

While trying to build the project I'm getting the following warnings and error. I can't figure out what is wrong here, I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18618187/1889768) answer and checked my **Framework Search Path** value and there is none in **BuildSettings**.

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/macbook/Desktop/<app_name>__main/build/Release-iphoneos'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/macbook/Desktop/<app_name>__main/build/Debug-iphoneos'
ld: framework not found Pods_<app_name>
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've been banging my head for several hours now and finally given up.

The path mentioned in the error does not exist and when I looked into where `build` folder is located in XCode project, I realized they are in a shared directory `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`. So I don't understand why XCode is looking for these files in the project's relative path, where `build` folder doesn't exist.

I'm using

XCode 10.1

CocoasPod <strike>1.5.3</strike> 1.8.4

MacOS High Sierra

Note: The same workspace builds successfully on another system.

**Edit:**

If I copy the `project.pbxproj` from the other system onto this one, the project on this machine builds successfully too. `project.pbxproj` is located under `*.xcodeproj` file.

Also if I select **Generic iOS Device** the project builds fine, but as soon as I switch to any other target device I get the same error.

**Edit 2:**

I see a couple of framework files in red in the left side `folder/directory`'s panel.

- `Foundation.framework`
- `Pods_<application_name>.framework`

**Solution:**

So right now I've found a solution what I believe to be a workaround and not the actual solution.

In my project's folder structure I saw multiple `.framework` files in red. some of them had different extensions then the ones present in the xCode package. So I updated them with the newer extension files and that got rid of most of the red file frameworks and left just one **Pods_.framework** the same framework in the error above. I removed the framework from the Libraries and Framework list in the `General` section. After I did that project build fine and I was able to run the app.

However, I noticed the `Pods_<app_name>.framework` file  is always regenerated after running `pod install`. So I have to manually remove this unwanted dependency from the list each time starting a new workspace which is pain to say the least.

And so now I'm looking for a way to correct this so I don't have to remove the `Pods_<app_name>.framework` file each time.

While I was searching for the solution I found a closed **`cocoapods`** bug which reported the same issue for an older version. I've lost the thread and cannot find it again otherwise I would've linked the bug.

As noted in one of the answer's comment I now have updated cocoapods version **1.8.4**.

**Edit 3:**

**Podfile**

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '7.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target '<app_name>' do

pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.39.0'

end
```

Comment: Did you try checking if there are any unwanted Frameworks listed in `Embedded Binaries` and `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` under `General`

Comment: There are no embedded binaries, as for Frameworks and Libraries they are all justifiable there (though I cannot be sure), I've inherited this project from a colleague who has quit. I've never worked on any apple app development before, so have close to no idea what is going on.

Comment: Although, and I haven't mentioned this in the post. But there are a couple frameworks which are showing red on the left folder/directory panel namely **`Foundation.Framework`** and **`Pods_<ApplicationName>.framework`**. The later's color normalize if I select `Generic iOS Device`.

Comment: Try deleting Podfile.lock and then pod update

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment and build logs I believe the podfile `Pods_<application_name>` is not available to your project(its added but not downloaded).

Pods are a way to share code across projects and maintain versioning.
You just need to update the pod so that it gets downloaded and added to your project. For that just launch Terminal app, `cd` to your project folder and fire `pod update` (you may refer to https://freakycoder.com/ios-notes-12-how-to-update-pods-249ecf88fe57)

If you do not have `pod` installed you can head to https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html

Comment: Already tried updating pod, didn't work. Will try again and let you know if it works.

Comment: Did you try updating `CocoaPod` itself? Else remove the Pod if not needed.

Comment: Yes, I updated cocoapods to the latest 1.8.3 I think and then reverted back to 1.5.3.

Comment: Yes, the issue is still there running `pod update` has no effect. As far as I can tell, the xCode version might be responsible for that, you see the system it runs on has xCode v10.3. Or it has something to do with linking the libraries to the project.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode has different build system for simulator and real devices. So it will generate different app for both. If you select any **Simulator** target then it will builds app for simulator and if you select **Generic iOS Device** or any real device target then it will builds different build.

May be you are using some frameworks which are builded for iOS devices, So 
follow this steps,

1. Differentiate that frameworks which gives you an error and remove that pods from your pod file and run `pod install` command and delete **DerivedData**.
2. Download that framework's code in your system.
3. Add project files of framework in your workspace. For that you can refer [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2435/_index.html) and [this](https://edit.theappbusiness.com/modular-ios-splitting-a-workspace-into-modules-331293f1090).

If you don't want to add whole code of framework in your project then you can add particular( for device or simulator ) build of framework in your xcode project.
For that follow this steps,

1. Open your downloaded project of framework.
2. Select any simulator target and build project.
3. Get generated `.framework` file from **Products** folder.
4. Add this framework in your project like [this](http://docs.onemobilesdk.aol.com/ios-ad-sdk/adding-frameworks-xcode.html).
5. Now build your project for simulator.
6. Follow above steps for devices target if you want to build for devices.

For Google Mobile Ads you can follow [this](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start) guidelines. Add the `-ObjC` linker flag to **Other Linker Flags** in your project's build settings

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did try to delete Derived data not once but many times. Did you read the question? I added a solution that worked for me. In the solution I pointed out a specific file `Pods_<app_name>.framework` which when deleted, fixed the issue, however as stated in the question the file comes back after each `pod install` and I have to remove the framework file again. Currently I'm looking for a way to not allow the file to come back.

Comment: You haven't understood my answer properly. I say that remove specific pod which gives you an error. Could you give me your pod list? I can solve your error because of i have faced this issue before.

Comment: I've added the `podfile`, there is only one dependency listed there.

Comment: The `-ObjC` flag is already present in the `Other Linker Flags`. Following is the complete instruction `-ObjC $(inherited)`.

Comment: Have you followed complete guidelines from https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start ?

Comment: Yes. Although I can't find which `info.plist` file to update, there are quite a few. Or is it only applicable for manual download?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201191/discussion-between-komal-goyani-and-abbas).

Answer (score 0):

I used to run into that problem once but I already solved it the same way @alxlive answer and it worked.

The problem happened to me because of the pod that we already installed.

During that time, I already installed my cocoapod for my project. Then, I added 2 new `Build Configurations`.

Your problem might be the same because you did mention copying others `project.pbxproj` from other system and it made your project work fine. So that might be the case.

By `deintegrate` and `install` the pod back on, that will solve the problem.

Comment: As I said earlier deleting the DerivedData and deintegrate pod didn't work. I tried that many times.

Answer (score 0):

Adding -ObjC $(inherited) in the Other Linker Flags fixes my issue

Answer (score 0):

For me it was due to having a space in the Configuration name like "Development Debug". Once I removed the space and made it "DevelopmentDebug", the error message went away.

Answer (score -1):

The pods need to be installed once per mac. The configuration set in the `project.pbxproj` depends on the Cocoapods version and the Xcode version on the machine.

Try the following:

1 - Delete the `Podfile.lock` file and the Pods folder from the local project

2 - Delete the content of the Derived Data folder: `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

3 - Run the command:

```
pod deintegrate
```

4 - Run the command

```
pod install
```

5 - Run the project again

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've found a sorta solution (still looking for a better approach). But before I found the solution I tried deleting all the files (probably 10 times I kid you not) you mentioned and deleting them didn't help.