# linking glfw static library with Xcode 4

Tags: static-libraries, osx-mountain-lion, xcode4.6, glfw

Okay I've been searching for hours to try and solve this but nothing has worked.  This problem is very similar to other posts, but I none of their solutions work.

So I am writing an OpenGL program using glew and glfw and for some reason I am unable to get the program to compile.  The error is on the include statement:

```
#include <GL/glfw.h>
```

and the error says 'GL.glfw.h' file not found.

I have followed all the instructions on the
[GLFW-2.7.8 Release Notes](http://www.glfw.org/release-2.7.8.html#using)
web page, which includes making glfw, and then importing the static library libglfw.a into Xcode. The library does show up under Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries, but apart from that Xcode doesn't seem to recognize it.  For example, under the File Inspector it detects the file type as "Default - data".

The static library is configured for 64-bit architecture, which I am running.

I have tried changing the search paths under Build Settings.

I have the following frameworks included: Cocoa, OpenGL, and IOKit.

Please let me know if there is any more information you need to help me solve this problem and thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my glew was not importing correctly and so glfw did not work either.
These are the steps I took:

- Changed the Base SDK from Latest OSX (10.8) to Current OSX.

After doing this, I "reduced" the error to an Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) error. Next:

- Added -lGLEW to Other Linker Flags.
- Added /opt/local/include/ to the header search paths
- Added /opt/local/lib/ to the library search paths

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064379/glew-apple-mach-o-linker-id-error) is where I found my answer.